# shell scripting display selective attributes using ls command

Tags: shell

Question : I have to display attributes of text files at a given path like size, permission, own, group , or all using.(using an if else like a menu )

I'm not sure how to display only selective attributes using ls command, ls -l gives everything which I don't need, then ls -sh1 gives only size....is there any way to use ls -l and display only certain parts of it ?

My Code :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " enter address in form : /home/rohan/../.."

read ARG

if [ -n "$ARG" ]; then
                        echo "entered path :$ARG"
                echo " files present are"
                     ls -sh1 $ARG"/"*.txt 
else
     ARG=$(pwd)
     echo "Path is :$ARG"
    echo " files present are"
             ls  -sh1 $ARG"/"*.txt 
  fi
```

Output: list of text files with size only.

So any way to restrict ls -l command ?

Comment: please display some sample output the ls command gives size and filename only.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

You can use the [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) command

```
stat --format="%y %n" *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is by using the 'find' command.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%b\n'
```

You can read more about formatting here:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm

at the section that starts with

> -printf format True; print format on the standard output, interpreting `\' escapes and`%' directives. Field widths and precisions can be
>   specified as with the `printf' C function. Unlike -print, -printf does
>   not add a newline at the end of the string. The escapes and directives
>   are: \a Alarm bell.

Comment: how do I display only certain attributes ?

Comment: You choose a list of attributes, then modify the print statement: if you want to display the byte size and the file name you would use: find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%p - %b\n'

Comment: Note that both `maxdepth` and `printf` are extensions to the standard `find`, and may not be available on all systems.